# Maximum acceptable frequency of sending broadcast in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

What is maximum acceptable frequency from your point of view or experience of sending broadcasts in Android to be received by BroadcastReceivers without performance impact?

Let's say we send only basic data in a Bundle without need for long deserialization.
I am going to send broadcasts only inside my app with LocalBroadcastManager.

In other words this question is about when you should stop using broadcasters and write you own implementation for faster usage and when you should not do it.

Comment: let's say that broadcasts should be used for notifying things. If you are going to transmit data at a steady rate, consider another way of transmitting. Also, if you are wondering, then you probably are already sending more broadcasts than you would like.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am asking, it is not clear what is considered to be a "steady" rate for Broadcasters.

Comment: another point is that broadcasts are good if you are sending data to possibly multiple targets. If not, service bindings are more efficient.

Comment: Actually I thought about service binding also. It may be the case as well.

Comment: @njzk2 if you want place your suggestion about binding service as separate answer and I +1 it at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you send data inside one app, I would advise you, instead of `BroadcastReceiver` use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) or even not use any type of broadcast receivers at all - just Observer Pattern ([here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07265/) good article on this topic).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know about LocalBroadcastManager and Observer pattern. That was not my question actually, I will update it and mention that I am going to use LocalBroadcastManager with broadcasts though.